# How to buffer OutputStream without any buffer limits in Java?

Tags: java, buffer, outputstream

*This case is a bit complex, I hope I will simplify it well.*

My task starts when I receive `PrintStream` where I am supposed to output some data. However entire task is calculating + printing, and I can print when I am done with calculation. So this could be 2-pass task, but I hope for 1-pass.

In order to achieve this, I would like to create some output buffer, do calculation and printing (to buffer) and then print out from the buffer to the real output stream.

So far so good, the problem is I am unable to find appropriate class for buffering -- `BufferedOutputStream` if I understand correctly, starts writing from the buffer when the buffer is full. I have to have much more strict control over it -- not writing to real output until I exactly say so.

**Question** -- is there any class appropriate for this task?

Comment: You can call `flush` on a BufferedOutputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ByteArrayOutputStream as your buffer. The byte array where this stream writes is enlarged automatically to hold everything you write.

When you are done generating output, just call the `writeTo` method to write the contents of the buffer to an output stream that writes to some actual device.

For further details see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html

Comment: An output stream is not a buffer.

Comment: I dont see your point. A chunk of memory can be used as a buffer. ByteArrayOutputStream manages a chunk of memory. Hence, it can be used to implement a buffer.

Comment: "The byte array where this stream writes is enlarged automatically to hold everything you write." This part is THE answer, thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc of the flush method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#flush%28%29) :

> Flushes this buffered output stream. This forces any buffered output
>   bytes to be written out to the underlying output stream.

Comment: I am not asking how to flush the buffer, I am asking how to prevent auto-flushing? Or there is no such thing as auto-flush in `BufferedOutputStream`?